# How do I align the viewport to a face normal?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow

I would like to align the view straight on to a face, perpendicular to the normal. How do I align the 3D viewport to the face of a mesh?

Comment: That's exactly what shift + numberPad 7 does as the answer below explains. If it's not working or not what you want, then please explain how what you want differs.

Comment: Posting .gif of what I'm getting

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SmC7v.gif. At the end of the gif I try to position the camera similar to how I want it.

Comment: that is object mode

Comment: @David *faceplam*. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In edit mode with a face selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> That will align the view to the [active](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217) face.
If you want to align the view to a different axis relative to the face, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 3</kbd> can be used. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> can be added to any of the key combinations to invert the view.
For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> will look at the "back" of a face.

For those of you without a numpad the same can be accessed through the menu.
From the 3D view header *View* > *Align View* > *Align View to Active*. Then pick the orientation you want (*Top* is used the most).
[image: view menu]

Do note that there can be faces that are not flat. In such cases the view will be aligned to the face, but any manipulation will warp the face.

This answer is valid for blender version 2.50 and up (including 2.8). For the 2.4 series the shortcut was <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, but I doubt you wanted to know that.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> will do this.

[image]

You may end up with a strange rotation around the view's local Z, in which case <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MW] Scroll</kbd> can be used to roll the view to a more preferred orientation.

Also note that <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> can be used to align the view parallel to the normal. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> can be added in to align to the opposite side.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + MMB` did not work for me - this zoomed in an awkward perspective. I used `Shift + Numpad 4` and `Shift + Numpad 6` instead to roll the view.

Comment: @Programmer Oh sorry, its Ctrl + Shift + MouseWheel, I've edited MW to "Scroll" hopefully that's a little clearer. Also glad you found a solution!