# Can't see bumps in wiewport, nor are they rendering

Tags: modeling, materials, objects

I just added a bump map to a object, and i can see the effect in the little window, but not the real thing. Also renders don't show it
[image]

Comment: Your texture has no coordinates

Comment: I'm quite new to this. What does no coordinates mean?

Comment: Please do some research see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40157/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-uv-map-a-complex-object

Answer (score 1):

If you have UV unwrapped your mesh, add in a texture coordinates node into your cycles like this:

[image: coordinates node]