# Relax some of the pinching in uv texture grid?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've unwrapped this object and probably cant fully straighten the map without causing insane stretching given the shape of the piece - however I wanted to know if theres a way to relax the pinching (3,4) on some parts of my model, would I have to make more cuts... and if so where? Or would it be fine?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: [What would be the easiest way to uv map a complex object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40157/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-uv-map-a-complex-object)

Comment: Have you tried the "minimize stretch" operation in UV editor?  It won't make up for insufficient seaming, but it can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i could really think of is projecting from view but I don't think that would be good for the model you're trying to texture.

Comment: Hey, I did try that but yeah sadly it doesnt help for relaxing some tight parts sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

IMO what you need to do is add seams to edges like this one.
[image: Added edge seams]

I don't know if you only want to texture this or if you plan to bake from a high-poly to low-poly model, but when baking normal maps you have to have at least an seam on each edge that exceeds your autosmooth degree threshold, at the absolute minimum. Right now you're using essentially no seams and hoping that an angle like this in 3D space --
[image: 90 degree angle]
Will somehow come out straight in the UV map. Which if you think about is asking a bit much.

My old trick when uv mapping hard surface objects is to set the *Select Linked Flat Faces* command to some free hotkey (Alt-shift-F for instance, it might actually already be that hotkey idk), set that degree to something that works for you, often 30degrees, and then use that tool to select areas, get the boundary loop and to get your baseline for seams on the model.

Like this:
[image: select flat faces workflow]