# Flatten mesh from uv's to retopo in blender 2.8

Tags: uv, shape-keys

I am trying to flatten by uv's a mesh that I can retopologize then morph back the retopo. The reason is I have a marvelous designer model with lots of folds, I spoke with an artist that uses 3ds max, but I am not going to go use that. I found a the tool he used in max called textool which was ported over to blender 2.79 and then someone make it work for blender 2.8. it does in fact flatten the mesh from uv's which uses a shape blend. I tried using retopoflow alpha I have but that won't work since the mesh is in this weird shape blend state. I could make it work using poly build but then the full problem is how to morph it back into its orignal mesh state.

Let me know what I might be able to do.

I did find this script on this site, but it doesn't seem to help this issue.
[Unwrap morph project.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149859/how-could-one-unwrap-morph-project-a-complex-3d-mesh-to-a-flat-surface)

here are some other things I found [video on Creating Mesh from uv layout in blender(easy)](https://youtu.be/YXHJX0WCoeA), this gets me there manually if i want to flatten to uv's which is fine, but the I need to morph back so. I found this [Video on Blender 2.8 Shapekeys and morphing](https://youtu.be/e675Ulc7QL4) problem is trying to some how morph back the retopo.

if your puzzled what I am trying to do and don't mind looking at a maya video, this guy, [Retopo geometry for animation, marvelous designer](https://lesterbanks.com/2016/03/retopologize-geometry-animation/)

Comment: Wow, I cannot express how long I've been searching on the internet for this exact question. I see that it's been 3 years since this posting. I hope that you receive this notification- have you made any further progress, or have you found any additional "hacks" or possibly tutorials to walk through this process? I'm trying to create something eerily similar to what you outlined in your video through Maya (I'm also animating shorts), only in my case importing a CLO 3D file (same complicated mesh) & using in blender. I'm about to delve into understanding your "answer" in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Wow so i got it, a bit weird process but I got it. you first have to use tex tools to flatten it. after that, you duplicate the flatten mesh. then delete shapekeys on flatten mesh of the duplicated version. then export the duplicated mesh. as i think obj might have been fbx. but point is it has to have shading on it. so reimport it. then on the new imported add a shapekey from the flattened uv version. so it blends back onto the mesh. then on the new imported version with shading. retopo on it. i used retopoflow alpha but you can use your choice of retopo workflow. after i applied on the retopoflow modifers. then added shrinkwrap on the retopo. then i just used the shape keys to put it back on mesh. then you can apply the shrinkwrap i believe then export from there.