# How to UV map a detailed object without getting distortion?

Tags: texturing, uv

i would like to unwrap a simple tyre with a lot of details, trying to avoid huge distortion and i'm not able to figure out how i could do it. I would need to figure out the unwrap of the lowpoly but also of the higpoly version.
Somebody has a suggestion?
[image]

Comment: I think you can add procedural texture without unwrapping https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g_5vykEZiw

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a repeating pattern, start by preparing a clean unwrap of *one* tiling segment (one checkerboard section).

[image]

This is using a **Mirror Modifier** to generate symmetry on the X axis, and an **Array Modifier** using Object Offset to get the rotation angle from an Empty. (In the modifier settings, enable **Merge**.)

**Note:** Shape Keys cannot be applied to a mesh that has modifiers. With this in mind, you *can* Apply the Mirror Modifier *before* creating your Shape Key if you want to... **but** since the left and right sides are the same this will equate to about twice as much work than is necessary. Instead, we can ***flip the UV unwrap result later*** - which is the approach I'm going to take in this example.

You can create a **Shape Key** to deform your mesh non-destructively, for very precise UV unwrapping. Make sure your newly created Shape Key is selected before you jump into Edit Mode and start working on the mesh.

[image]

How you get your mesh into your ideal shape for projection is up to you. In my example I started with **Smooth Vertices**.

[image]

I've marked the seams around the extrusions just to make them more visually obvious and easily selectable while editing here.

**Tip:** You can select a seam island by selecting a single face inside it and then doing **Select Linked** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>). You can then Grow (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>) or Shrink (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>) that selection if desired.

[image]

Then, with my **Pivot Point** set to **Median Point**, I selected each edge loop and scaled it on an axis to straighten them.

[image]

The vertical edges can be straightened on both X and Y *simultaneously* if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (to omit only Z) while scaling.

For uncurling the curved geometry of the tire into a nearly flat shape, you can use the **3D Cursor** as your **Pivot Point** and **Rotate** the mesh in sections, deselecting as you go.

[image]

<sup>Above: Using [Circle Select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#circle-select) and Rotate to straighten geometry.</sup>

Using these methods you should be able to get your UV layout exactly as you want it.

This takes a little time, but it's worth it if you want to get a really clean grid of a UV layout.

(Note that the Follow Active Quads projection method often works well for simple grids, but it won't handle the topology of these extrusions well.)

In Edit Mode, facing the direction you want your UV layout to be projected in (in my case Front Orthographic View), press <kbd>U</kbd> and choose the **Project From View** method.

[image]

In the UV Editor, select your unwrapped result and move it precisely to the bottom left corner of the UV Editor's square area. Zoom in as far as possible to make sure it's right on the edge if you want a perfect flip with no gaps.

I didn't devote much attention to UV stretching in my example here, but now would be a good time to make a preview material for your model with a simple "color grid" texture, and see which faces should be scaled up or down to make optimal use of your texture space.

If you think you might need to make small adjustments later, you can assign parts of your geometry to Vertex Groups to make them easily selectable. But of course making adjustments to the original geometry beforehand is best.

Save As. Next comes a destructive edit. Delete the shape key you used for unwrapping. Then delete the "Basis" shape key. Now you can **Apply** the **Mirror Modifier**.

In the UV Editor, enable **UV Sync Selection** by clicking the button with two arrows going in opposing directions.

[image]

Now when you select the other half (Mirror Modifier result) of your mesh, only the 3D Viewport's *selected* geometry will show as *selected* in the UV Editor.

Set the UV Editor's **Pivot Point** to the **2D Cursor**.

Check that your 2D Cursor is precisely in the bottom left of the UV area (this is its default position, but you can check in the **View** tab (press <kbd>N</kbd> if you don't see it). It allows you to specify the X and Y coordinates of the 2D Cursor.

Now with the mirror result part of your mesh selected in the UV Editor, **Scale** `-1` along the X axis.

[image: Flipping the selected part of the UV map by scaling -1 along the X axis.]

Next, select the entire UV map, **Grab** (<kbd>G</kbd>) then move it along the X axis by `1`. Everything should now be centered and you can **Scale** it to get it right in the bounds of the UV area. You will need to position the **2D Cursor** at `0.5` on the X axis.

[image: Scaling the UV map to be within the UV area]

Remove the marks from the seams we used before. **Mark Seams** only on the edges that will be the boundary for this repeating segment of the tire.

[image]

If you want the UV map to be for just one segment - you're done. *But* I'm guessing you probably want it to cover the en*tire* tire so that any textures you give it will look unique and not repetitive. In that case, keep following along.

Save As. **Apply** the **Array Modifier**.

[image]

Now for the final steps of the process. **Select Linked** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) the newly generated geometry from the Array Modifier *result* in the 3D Viewport and in the UV Editor move the UV island up on Y so that it *touches* where the last UV island leaves off. (It helps if you set the **Snapping** method to **Vertex**, or if you've scaled it to some rounded number so you can key in the distance to move it by.)

You can then repeat this process, adding a new **Array Modifier**, adjusting its setting and the rotation of the Empty, **Applying** it, and then placing the newly generated UV islands.

[image]

The final time you use the Array Modifier, to go "full circle", check the Merge settings and enable **First and Last Copies**. This connects the last array segment back to the first one.

Once you've got your UV islands laid out the way you want them, consider adding some margin. Scale them in a little bit so they don't touch the outer edges or each other.

[image]

You're done!

Comment: Very useful workflow, i forgot to mention in my post that i would need the unwrap of the lowpoly but also the higpoly version. I don't know if with this method is possible to unwrap the higpoly, because the seams gets distorted.

Comment: @matibuc In that case you are looking at creating two UV maps. Unfortunately the poly count determines the the topology, and the topology dictates the basis for what the UV map will look like. You can reposition UV data as long as the topo doesn't change - but once it does, so must the UV map. You can however have some source of color etc you will bake from, and then the bake result can be captured onto both the hi-poly and low-poly meshes. This might save you some repetition in your work. But the UV mapping is bound to the topology of the geometry. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope, no I'm sorry but I didn't understand much.  I didn't understand how I could unwrap the higpoly.  Do I need to change the workflow from the one you showed me above?

Comment: @matibuc The workflow in my answer will work for both high/low-poly. It will work for any sort of detailed mesh object. It's a method that affords the artist precise control over how the UV map looks. And I intended my answer to be general, so hopefully it will also be useful to people making things besides tires. ;-) But in your case, I should ask: what kind of texture(s) do you want to map onto your tire? Because you might be able to get away with keeping it simple. For example, if you just want to add a logo to the side of the tire or something, there's no need to UV map the tread geometry.

Comment: Dear friend, i do not have the tools to really understood the process you showed to me above, and how to apply it to my specific case, and also to other cases. How it may be possible to handle an higer poly mesh since the seamlines are no more stright but all stretched?.  I'd like to deepen your workflow to improve my UV unwrap skills but i can't figure out how could we do. It's a little bit tricky to do it here. Anyway i'm trying to reach a clean UV to be able to export the model and texture it in Substance Painter.

Comment: @matibuc I see. There are several different concepts involved here. For example: modifiers, scaling, pivot point, UV unwrapping methods, shape keys, UV Sync, and seams. None of these tools/operations are especially advanced on their own, but if you've got to learn them all at once I can understand how that might feel daunting. The good news is that each of these is very useful to know anyway, and worth learning if you plan to continue 3D in the long term. Now that you mention Substance Painter, I understand the need for texture detail all over the tire. Maybe search "UV unwrap basics" first.

Comment: I'm not so beginner and i know all the tools you mentioned but i'm struggling understanding the process in its entirety, and how it could be applied to other unwrap and in which cases. I think that if i fail to consolidate this workflow i will miss out on a very useful and important tool. Don't you have a link to some tutorial that explains it step by step, or may i contact you in private for a better understanding?

Comment: @matibuc There's actually [an answer I posted several years back](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40161/2952) that is very similar to this one. It might be easier for you to follow because it uses the familiar Suzanne monkey mesh, and it has more animated GIFs to detail the steps. Plus, sometimes it helps to get one more explanation of the same subject in a different way. How that answer differs from this one here is that this answer addresses the tiling of the repeating shape of the tire, and the other involves ripping the mesh because Suz has a closed geometry. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here I marked the region where u should put the seams,[image] If ya want to avoid distortion, I know the Treads part will give distortion bcz of the sides. What you should do is get an addon called UV squares it's free and select the side loops of each of 3 tread islands and make it straight using UV squares addon.As in second images [image]   It will work. you might need to do some pinning also to get good shapes. if ya can send the model maybe I can explain the process more easily
Second method is making those tread square each islands which is far easy but not efficient