# automatically detects 3D view by selecting one face mesh

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, workflow, shortcut, orthographic

> hi instead of using numpad ( front / back /left / right / bottom / top
>   ) to locate the desired view , is there a operation in blender that
>   automatically detects/change the view by just selecting a face of a mesh object

[image: Frontal View + Ortho at left 3d View]

reason im looking for this command

1. **less hotkeys** ( 1 only )
2. **Quickly locate the view**
3. **Avoid confusion** ( sometimes i tend be confuse whether if its left/right or front back of the mesh which leads to slowdown of workflow )

thank you for answers

Comment: You can open one more 3D View editor, make it really small and look at it just to navigate your mesh. Also to save  time for navigation it's useful to look at the mini-axes located in the bottom left corner. And probably new script should be written to make the view behave like you ask when selecting a face.

Comment: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal

Comment: hi thank you for quick reply about http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal but it gives me this result http://imgur.com/gxxABKN .. is there a way it will not rotate the view ?

Comment: to add ..  i want it to remain at default view like in quad view box ( frontal view + ortho ) where there is no rotation ..thank you

Comment: in the quad view mode the view can be aligned only in the upper right view (perspective)... the other views are fixed by definition...  I don't know anymore what you want...