# How to align the view or a camera to a certain face or object

Tags: uv, 3d-view, camera, faces

Is there a way to align the view or a camera to be perpendicular to a specific face or object using it's normal? The thing I am trying to acheive, is to use the view to unwrap a face, so I can use it later for neighboring faces unwrap, but I'm trying to do this precisely, not by eying it.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal

Comment: Btw, were can I ask questions about BSE?

Comment: @Georges http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, select the face and press<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>.

Comment: Shift + Z will toggle Rendered view shading, even in Edit mode, what is the name of the operation that this shortcut trigger?

Comment: @Georges Sorry,I meant 7 not Z