# Scaling multiple rings on cylinder to the same size

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am trying to scale different sized rings on a cylinder to the same size, like turning a vase into a pipe shape. I would be glad if one can tell me a shortcut, I am trying to do it one by one, and I guess there is an easier way.

Edit: I am attaching a screenshot. On the left side I have the representative model I want to modify, and on the right side I have the expected result. I am looking for a way to select all the rings and bring them to the same diameter.

Thanks

[image: 2 cylinders]

Comment: Images of what you are trying to do might help us understand. Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot and a more detailed description of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I assume you mean [edge loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html#edge-loops) and not [edge rings](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html#edge-rings) because edge loops are selected on your screenshot.*

It's possible to scale edge loops one by one to the size of desired loop or to recreate them from scratch.

**Scale edge loops**

1. Activate [*Snap During Transform*](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#transform-snapping) tool. Set *Type of Element to Snap* to *Vertex* and choose *Closest*.
2. Select one of edge loops of the mesh (hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking <kbd>RMB</kbd> on them).
3. If object is oriented along Global axes, as by default, press <kbd>S</kbd> to activate Scale tool, and with pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> restrict scaling only to 2 axes (X and Y).

   3.1. If the object was rotated and is *not* oriented along global axes (X Y Z), then you can [align view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal) to the face perpendicular to the edge being edited *or* create [custom transform orientation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html#custom-orientations). Depending on the method choosed you'll need to change transform orientation either to View or to custom one and lock not global rather than View / custom axes.
4. Hover mouse cursor over vertex of the edge loop serving as loop with desired scale. Once selected edge loop is scaled as desired click with <kbd>LMB</kbd> / press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

[image: GIF of scaling edge loops according to another one]

**Recreate edge loops**

There are many ways to do that (one is to dissolve them one by one), the fastest one would be to select all the edge loops, delete faces and use *Bridge Edge Loops* to connect the remained ones.

[image: screenshot of recreating edge loops]