# Vertex Orientation in an Object

Tags: modeling

Why vertex "A" is aligned at different axis as compared to VErtex "B" & "C"?
How can "A" be aligned similar to other two vertex(B & C)?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why vertex orientation is useful for you in this situation?

Comment: I want to drag these coordinate along x (Red Direction). But notice the vertex A alignment :(...hope there a solution.

Comment: Instead try G G and hold Alt

Comment: A, B & C moves initially properly(vertically) but after certain distance the only points which drags is C. This makes a segment between B & C tapered. Cool trick but not usable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex normals are determined by the interpolated face normals of the connected faces. When you have the transform orientation set to *Normal* the Z axis is aligned with the vertex normal.
Trouble is that there is no way for blender to know how to align the manipulator on the corners. It still has the Z aligned correctly, but that is not helping you here.

See in this image I have a mesh similar to yours, selected at different times in two different spots. Note that even though the manipulator is pointed in the "wrong" direction in the bottom corner, it *is* still correctly aligned with the vertex normal (blue line on each vertex).
[image: vertex normals and manipulator]

---

As a work around you could [align the view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15046/2217) to one of the faces, with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>. Then change the *Transform Orientation* (in the 3D view header) to "*View*".