# How do I align a view to the plane intersecting selected vertices

Tags: 3d-view

new to Blender, working through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjW6r10Mlqs). I'm about to extrude out the trunk of my elephant, but one vertex from my extrusion face (see screenshot, the bottom right one in the selected loop) forms a sharp angle. I'd like to move this vertex to soften the angle, but want to ensure that it remains "straight" relative to the other selected vertices. ie: at present, if I just hit 'g' and move it around, the side view no longer shows those vertices as a straight line. I hope that makes sense!

How can I align the view to the plane intersecting those vertices, so that moving that vertex left and right with my mouse will keep it in the same plane? I have tried align view to active with those vertices selected, but this seems to align the view to the entire object, not just the selected vertices.

[image: elephant front and side views]

**Edit**: based on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal), Shift-Numpad 7 looks like what I want. However, when just selecting that loop, it gets me to this:

[image: elephant post shift-numpad 7]

I assume it is basing the orientation off the single white vertex rather than the whole loop? My workaround for now is to select the loop, create a face, rotate with shift-numpad 7, delete the face, then do the edits I want to do. This works, but seems pretty kludgy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

just rotate the whole loop with R from the side view then grab, move, and scale the whole loop into place.  for the trunk to have a smoother curve, you're going to have to add more edge loops with Cntrl R.

Edit: part of the reason is your topology, i just edited your image a little to give it a more practical topology. you just gotta move your vertices around a little near the mouth and neck area.  take a look at the edited reference image below[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I might not have been clear. Right now I'm not trying to model the mouth of the elephant. I just don't want the trunk to have a sharp corner on it, and I'd like to do that whilst keeping the vertices straight.

I want to move the bottom right vertex on that left view whilst maintaining that they appear in a straight line on the view on the right. Were I to just grab and move it right now, I'd get "zig zags" on the right, because the left view is not aligned to the selected loop. I hope that makes more sense, and thanks again for helping out!

Comment: oh, then just move that vertex along the X Axis.  press G then X.  you could also try beveling that vertex first selecting only that single vertex then press Shift Ctrl B and move your mouse.  scroll wheel up increases number of cuts, scroll wheel down decreases number of cuts.