# How to view a face as it is (and not modified by where it is)?

Tags: camera

How to view a face as it is and not modified by where it is?

For example, I created an icosphere and I want the camera to show a face as it is: an equilateral triangle for a reference image.

Comment: Sounds like you want to align the camera with the face normal and use orthographic projection. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks! "normal" was the word. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal