# How can I look exactly at normal?

Tags: modeling

I want to edit my object with comfort like when I use gizmo axis selection, but my object is not placed exactly on axis:
[image]

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+numpad7

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but you can try switching the "Transform orientation" to "normal":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your annswer. I want to place the viewport camera exactly on the normal front

Comment: so follow this guide: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal

@Geri comment was the  right one